# Data Factory not recognising array for 'flatten' operation

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Flaten inside of Data Factory, I keep on getting the error

```
The inner value type of the 'Unroll by' structure '{Category Numbers}' must be array type (e.g. structue of arrays, array of arrays)
```

Whilst I just did a 'Split' operation, this is the preview of the column 'Cateogry Numbers' from the previous step.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT EXPECTED OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: can you please share your flatten activity screenshot along with data preview screenshot from earlier activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flatten` transformation transforms the array data to one row per item in each array.

[**Unroll by**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten#unroll-by):

> Select an array to unroll. The output data will have one row per item in each array. If the unroll by the array in the input row is null or empty, there will be one output row with unrolled values as null.

**Here is an example of how the flatten works**:

In the example column "**data rows**" is an array that needs to be flattened as one row per item in each array.

[image]

Output of flatten transformation.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Source:
Note: remove the space in the column name

[image]

Data preview of source:

[image]

Flatten transformation:

[image]

preview of flatten transformation

[image]

Aggregate: Use aggregate to remove duplicate row.

[image]

[image]

Aggregate preview:

[image]

sink:

[image]

Comment: I see, appreciate the explanation! What would then be the step I need to take in order to split it so I only get one product to category number? So the first product would appear in the list 5 times for all the categories.

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Hey, I have made an edit, I simply want one instance of Product to Category per row, two rows, long format

Comment: Everysingle tutorial I see online point to the flatten transformation, I have no idea how else to flatten this data...

Comment: Can you try removing space between column name {Category Numbers} and use the same flatten transformation? Updated my answer with the latest findings

Comment: Dude, it was literally the space in the column name! That is ridiculous! I appreciate you looking into this for me - helped out a lot, cheers! :)